# Is there a trade-off for memory to memory DMA transfer when the data size is small?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4

I am learning about the STM32 F4 microcontroller. I'm trying to find out about limitations for using DMA.

Per my understanding and research, I know that if the data size is small (that is, the device uses DMA to generate or consume a small amount of data), the overhead is increased because DMA transfer requires the DMA controller to perform operations, thereby unnecessarily increasing system cost.

I did some reaserch and found the following:

> Limitation of DMA
>
> CPU puts all its lines at high impedance state so that the DMA controller can then transfer data directly between device and memory without CPU intervention. Clearly, it is more suitable for device with high data transfer rates like a disk.
>   Over a serial interface, data is transferred one bit at a time which makes it slow to use DMA.

Is that correct? What else do I need to know?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "overhead" (of what exactly, instructions, speed, power consumption, ... ?) this can can be true yes. Setting up the DMA controller for a memory to memory transfer on a STM32F4 requires at the very least 4x peripheral register writes which will take a couple of CPU cycles. So for small data sizes this might actually perform worse than letting the CPU copying it.

Comment: Your question is not possible to answer. DMA is built in and there is no additional *"system cost"*. DMA use cased are so different - the answer is possible only on the actual application level but not generally. IMO as a beginner you should avoid any microoptimization considerations.

Comment: There is much you haven't told us about how your system is designed (I imagine it's an embedded board system?) or your use cases.  But this link might help: https://embedds.com/using-direct-memory-access-dma-in-stm23-projects/

Comment: u are right that is a stm32f4

Comment: I believe the learning target is to read the STM32F4 reference manual [\[RM0090\]](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00031020-stm32f405-415-stm32f407-417-stm32f427-437-and-stm32f429-439-advanced-arm-based-32-bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf),
(specifically, section 10 (DMA)) in conjunction with the "using stm32 f2/f4/f7" application note [\[AN4031\]](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00046011-using-the-stm32f2-stm32f4-and-stm32f7-series-dma-controller-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and provide a discussion of configuration options and performance considerations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vinci and @0___________ (f.k.a. @P__J__) already pointed out,

1. A DMA controller works autonomously and doesn't create overhead on the CPU it supplements (at least not by itself). But:
2. The CPU/software must perform some instructions to configure the DMA and to trigger it or have it triggered by some peripheral. For this, it needs CPU time and program memory space (usually ROM). Besides, it usually needs some additional RAM in variables to manage the software around the DMA.

   Hence, you are right, using a DMA comes with some kinds of overhead.

And furthermore,

3. The DMA transfers make use of the memory bus(es) that connect the involved memories/registers/peripherals to the DMA controller. That is, while the DMA controller does its own work, it may cause the CPU which it tries to offload to stall in the meantime, at least for short moments when the data words are transferred (which in turn sum up for longer transfers...).

---

On the other hand, a DMA doesn't only help you to reduce the CPU load (regarding total CPU time to implement some feature). If used "in a smart way", it helps you to reduce software latencies to implement different functions because one part of the implementation can be "hidden" behind the DMA-driven data transfer of another part (unless, both rely on the same bus resources - see above...).

Comment: The core has a priority over DMA. It is almost not noticeable. On the other side DMA will be "stalled" by the core access. To prevent it (for really intensive and time critical DMA transactions)  to operate on the other memory segment than the core .

Answer (score 3):

> DMA -CPU puts all its lines at high impedance state

I do not know where did you take it from - but you should not use this source any more.

Frequency of the DMA transfers do not matter unless you reach the the BUS throughput. you can transfer one byte per week, month, year, decade ..... and it is absolutely OK.

In the STM32 microcontrollers it is a very important feature as we can transfer data from/to external devices even if the uC is in low power mode with the core (CPU) sleeping. DMA controller can even wake up the core when some conditions are met.

Comment: Is that any other suggest reference about the limitation of using DMA transfer for slow periodic data?

Answer (score 0):

**The information is right** in that using a DMA requires some development work and some runtime to manage the DMA transfer itself (see also 
[a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723561/is-there-a-trade-off-for-memory-to-memory-dma-transfer-when-the-data-size-is-sma/61728669#61728669)
here), which may not be worth the benefits of using DMA. That is, for small portions of data one doesn't gain as much performance (or latency) as during big transfers. On embedded systems, DMA controllers (and their channels) are limited resources so it is important to consider which part of the function benefits from such a resource most. Therefore, one would usually prefer using DMA for the data transfers to/from disks (if it is about "payload data" such as large files or video streams) over slow serial connections.

**The information is wrong**, however, in that DMA is not worth using on serial interfaces as those only transfer a single bit at a time. Please note that microcontrollers (as your
[STM32F4](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32-high-performance-mcus/stm32f4-series/stm32f407-417/stm32f407vg.html))
have built-in peripheral components that convert the serial bit-by-bit stream into a byte-by-byte or word-by-word stream, which can easily be tranferred by DMA in a helpful way - especially if the size of the packets is known in advance and software doesn't have to analyse a non-formatted stream. Furthermore, not every serial connection is "slow" at all. If the project uses, e. g., an SPI flash chip, then the SPI serial connection *is* the one used for data transfer.

Comment: the link & and the answer is misleading.  *"in that DMA is not worth using on serial interfaces as those only transfer a single bit at a time"* - that is  a non sense as DMA only transfers as minimum bytes.

Comment: Yep, that's why I wrote such an information is wrong.

Comment: Do u have any other suggest reference about limitation of using DMA transfer for slow periodic data? I hope can learn more about that.

Comment: @P__J__ please re-read what HelpingHand said.  It sounds like you're both in *AGREEMENT* ;)   Jia Hoo Loh - you've got your answer: if you're willing to invest the effort, DMA transfer will help (if only by offloading the CPU), regardless of how little data, or how infrequently you send it.